# Javascript: Reusing a dynamically created DOM object on next page loads

Tags: javascript, dom, caching

I have 20K+ values to display in a Combox Box. The HTML was getting huge so in order to reduce the HTML load time, I stored all the values in an array in localStorage. Next, I used javascript and dynamically added all options to that Combo Box. Till here every thing is fine, however now I want to even avoid the step of populating the combo box on every page load. What I want is to store the populated Combo Box DOM object somewhere and on every page load reuse that object. I have already tried localStorage but it's failing, probably because the list is too big (RnD to figure that out is going in parallel).

Is there any thing else I can utilize to cache dynamically formed DOM objects so that they can be used all across application on different pages with repeated re-loads without going through the pain of dynamically populating them over and over again.

Comment: Would an autocomplete textbox that looks up values from the server be a better UI? 20K+ entries in a dropdown sounds like it would take quite a while to find what you're looking for.

Comment: I am avoiding any subsequent server trips once the user has logged in thats why utilizing localStorage for many things. However, I will explore some options to base atuocomplete on localStorage instead of Ajax call to server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a partial template html for the combobox,and precompile it. (Handlebars/Moustache)
2. Load the file dynamically on the first page
3. For the other pages, you can use this cached partial html

Comment: seems promising. let me work on this and I'll revert back. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was exactly what I was looking for. Worked like a charm.... :)